# Messing around with flask , my form page is not functioning the button is not working. It should display a string that says thank you for submitting

Tags: python, forms

I have created a flask application of the soccer tournament. I am having issues with the form page, the submit button should display a text "Hello" + string + "for submitting!". I created a additional html page named display that displays this. Once, I filled out  the form it did not do nothing.

```
#import the flask module 
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/teams")
def teams():
    return render_template('teams.html') 

@app.route("/form", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def form():
    #get the method of the post and the method of the get 
    if request.method == "POST"  and request.form.get('submit'):
        string = request.form.get('name')
        feedback = "Hello" + string + "\n Thank you for submiting!"
        return render_template('display.html').format(feedback = feedback)
    else:
        return render_template('form.html').format(feedback="")
    
#run the program 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Home html

Comment: `display.html: <p>{feedback}</p>` I believe you need two `{{ }}` around the variable name.  `{{feedback}}`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other comments, you likely wanted this line:

```py
if request.method == "POST"  and request.form.get('submit'):
```

to be

```py
if request.method == "POST"  and request.form.get('user'):
```

to check for the user parameter in the form. This would redirect you to display.html, but following this you would likely want to incorporate the changes others suggested as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing or using the variable correctly. You'll need double braces: `{{feedback}}`. And while `render_template` returns a string, you should pass the variable to `render_template` directly: `render_template("form.html", feedback=feedback)`.

Additionally, the input for the second `name` isn't closed in `form.html` (should probably be `comments` as well, and your image path in `teams.html` should use the full path from server root (and forward slashes, not backslashes).